# How to Compare Values of two Dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df` and `df2` like this

```
    id  initials
0   100 J
1   200 S
2   300 Y

    name  initials
0   John   J
1   Smith  S
2   Nathan N
```

I want to compare the values in the `initials` columns found in (`df` and `df2`) and copy the name (in `df2`) which its initial is matching to the initial in the first dataframe (`df`)

```
import pandas as pd

for i in df.initials:
    for j in df2.initials:
        if i == j:
        # copy the name value of this particular initial to df
```

The output should be like this:

```
     id name
 0   100 Johon
 1   200 Smith
 2   300
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about?:

```
df3 = df.merge(df2,on='initials',
                   how='outer').drop(['initials'],axis=1).dropna(subset=['id'])
>>> df3
      id    name
0  100.0    John
1  200.0   Smith
2  300.0     NaN
```

So the 'initials' column is dropped and so is anything with `np.nan` in the 'id' column.

If you don't want the `np.nan` in there tack on a `.fillna()`:

```
df3 = df.merge(df2,on='initials',
                   how='outer').drop(['initials'],axis=1).dropna(subset=['id']).fillna('')
>>> df3
      id   name
0  100.0   John
1  200.0  Smith
2  300.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df1 
    id initials                                                                                                                                                               
0  100        J                                                                                                                                                               
1  200        S                                                                                                                                                               
2  300        Y 

df2
     name initials                                                                                                                                                            
0    John        J                                                                                                                                                            
1   Smith        S                                                                                                                                                            
2  Nathan        N
```

Use Boolean masks: `df2.initials==df1.initials` will tell you which values in the two `initials` columns are the same.

```
0     True                                                                                                                                                                    
1     True                                                                                                                                                                    
2    False
```

Use this mask to create a new column:

```
df1['name'] = df2.name[df2.initials==df1.initials]
```

Remove the `initials` column in `df1`:

```
df1.drop('initials', axis=1)
```

Replace the `NaN` using `fillna(' ')`

```
df1.fillna('', inplace=True) #inplace to avoid creating a copy

    id   name                                                                                                                                                                 
0  100   John                                                                                                                                                                 
1  200  Smith                                                                                                                                                                 
2  300
```