# Comparing elements of a column from two different dataframes where the condition is based on a function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of which `df1.bbox_col` and `df2.bbox_col` are one of their columns which are as below:

df1.bbox_col:

```
          bbox_col
 0   [20, 30, 40, 50]
 1   [5, 15, 48, 90]
 2   [111, 72, 51, 18]
```

df2.bbox_col:

```
          bbox_col
 0   [26, 62, 72, 56]
 1   [2, 18, 43, 95]
 2   [123, 90, 48, 51]
 3   [156, 76, 65, 97]
 4   [65, 76, 87, 32]
 5   [54, 78, 34, 56]
```

I have a function `area` which takes in two bounding box numpy arrays and returns a float value.

```
def area(bbox1, bbox2):
    some operations...

    return float_val
```

I want to apply this function to all elements of both the columns and if the returned value is greater than `thresh` i.e., `float_val > thresh`, then update `df1[index1][bbox_col] = df2[index2][bbox_col]` in the dataframe.

Else if `float_val < thresh`, then append the row of `df2.iloc[index2]` to `df1`.

I tried to implement this by iterating over rows of both dataframes and comparing as below:

```
for index1, row1 in df1:
    for index2, row2 in df2:
        if area(row1.bbox_col, row2.bbox_col) > thresh:
            df1.iloc[index1]['bbox_col'] = row2.bbox_col
        else:
            df1 = df1.append(df2.row)
```

So basically, what I want to do is to check if a particular element matches the criteria and replace it, or else append the row of the second dataframe to the first.

I am trying to get rid of both the problems as below:

1. I see that my code is appending the rows multiple times. Probably because of nested looping(but I am not able to pinpoint or rectify that).
2. I was looking for a **more optimized or vectorized way** of implementing this.

I was considering some function like df.apply() to do this, but it takes only one dataframe.

Lastly, I am looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650273/how-to-compare-values-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas), but with `on=` being a function in `pd.merge`...

Comment: 2 notes. (1) For an optimized / vectorised method, you need to use NumPy arrays or (at a minimum) expand your series of lists into 4 columns. Remember `df.apply` with a custom function is never vectorised. (2) Are you not concerned about vectorising `area`? This is likely to end up being the main bottleneck, but we don't know what it does..

Comment: @jpp As you mentioned...  I am actually checking how much area of the two bboxes overlap(in percentage) in ```area``` func. Therefore, I need to check the overlapping area of each and every bbox in ```df2``` with each and every bbox in ```df1```. I was looking forward to use ```df.merge``` on a column based on a function...