# How can I use Pandas in Excel to get lines?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I use Pandas to do a loop and verify if the name in sheet1 is equal the name in sheet2?

After verify the name equal, the program should get a whole line of the sheet1 and sheet2 and save the new workbook.

The final result should a new workbook with union of the lines in each spreadsheet

I know how use Openpyxl, but I want to learn Pandas. In my researches I did not find answers.

## example sheet1:

[image]

## example sheet2:

[image]

Comment: First read the excel sheets in with `df1 = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')`, do the same for sheet2 and call it `df2`. Then merge the two dataframes: `df1.merge(df2, on='NOME')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the file into pandas as a DataFrame using

```
Import pandas as pd
df  = pd.read_excel("yourfile.xlsx")
```

You can read more about that in the [pandas documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You would create a DataFrame for each file. The two DataFrames can be [merged on duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650273/how-to-compare-values-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas). The resulting DataFrame can then be exported using pandas.

```
Import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx")
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='NOME')
df3.to_excel("mergeFile.xlsx")
```

Comment: thanks. I am studying the documentation. It was very dificult to find, but today, I found.